# Add previous text when replacing comma with new line in bash

Tags: bash

I've got this output:

```
[matt@gateway output]# cat test2.txt
TM1ITP1-TMNLSTP1 SLC00=0,SLC01=0,SLC02=0,SLC03=0
```

if I just use

```
cat test2.txt | tr "," "\n"
```

I'll end up very near to what I'm trying to achieve:

```
TM1ITP1-TMNLSTP1 SLC00=0
SLC01=0
SLC02=0
SLC03=0
```

But how can I eventually add the term "TM1ITP1-TMNLSTP1" to all the new lines after replacing the comma with a new line?

```
TM1ITP1-TMNLSTP1 SLC00=0
TM1ITP1-TMNLSTP1 SLC01=0
TM1ITP1-TMNLSTP1 SLC02=0
TM1ITP1-TMNLSTP1 SLC03=0
```

Could I still need to use tr or there is something else I can try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd just use Perl:

```
cat test2.txt | perl -pe 's/,/\nTM1ITP1-TMNLSTP1/g'
```

If the `TM1ITP1-TMNLSTP1` part should be dynamic, it gets a little more complicated. Let's assume it's always the first non-empty sequence of non-whitespace characters on a line that you want to repeat across the rest of the (comma-separated) items. Then I'd go with:

```
perl -pe 's/,/\n$prefix/g if ($prefix) = /(\S+)/'
```

Alternatively, if you always have two (whitespace-separated) columns and only the second one contains commas, you could also do it like this:

```
perl -lane 'print map { "$F[0] $_\n" } split /,/, $F[1]'
```

(The `-a` option automatically splits the fields into the `@F` array, so `$F[0]` is the prefix and `$F[1]` is the comma-separated list.)

Answer (score 0):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk '{n=split($2,a,","); for(i=1;i<=n;i++) print $1,a[i]}' file

TM1ITP1-TMNLSTP1 SLC00=0
TM1ITP1-TMNLSTP1 SLC01=0
TM1ITP1-TMNLSTP1 SLC02=0
TM1ITP1-TMNLSTP1 SLC03=0
```

Answer (score 0):

sed is simple enough.

```
$: cat test2.txt
TM1ITP1-TMNLSTP1 SLC00=0,SLC01=0,SLC02=0,SLC03=0

$: sed 's/,/\nTM1ITP1-TMNLSTP1 /g' test2.txt
TM1ITP1-TMNLSTP1 SLC00=0
TM1ITP1-TMNLSTP1 SLC01=0
TM1ITP1-TMNLSTP1 SLC02=0
TM1ITP1-TMNLSTP1 SLC03=0
```

...you did google this, didn't you? XD